# Automating the switch in any circuit using 8051

Tags: switches

I've got the circuit that record and play back voice ,

here is the circuit,

[image: diagram]
<sub>(source: [engineersgarage.com](https://www.engineersgarage.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/Original/wysiwyg_imageupload/4214/Voice-Recorder-and-Playback_0.gif))</sub>

Mode of operation

1. ```
   Record Mode
   ```

The LED glows when the IC records the voice obtained through the Mic. A single voice message up to 20 seconds can be recorded. The IC remains in the recorded mode as long as the RecL pin 27 is grounded. Recoding will be terminated with the last memory when 20 seconds is over. The Speaker driver will automatically mutes in the recording mode. By changing the value of the OscR resistor R1 it is possible to increase the recording period as follows.

1. ```
       R1 52K 20 Sec.
   ```
2. ```
       R1 67 K   24 Sec
   ```
3. ```
       R1 89 K   30 Sec.
   ```

What i want to do is to use 8051 Microcontroller instead of the playback switch,
this is how the circuit suppose to work,

when the record switch is Closed , the timer starts and stays for 30 seconds and after 30 seconds of recording the playback wire which is suppose to be connect with 8051 muse be closed to play back the recorded voice,

I know how to generate delays of specific time using 8051 , and i know all about 8051 programming, what i need is the idea to connect 8051 at playback switch .

Could somebody help ? i just need an idea as i am still a beginner

Comment: Are you interested in controlling the *record* switch using the 8051 as well?  It is slightly more complicated in their example circuit since it controls the bias to the microphone.

Comment: 8051 is somewhat ancient, are you sure you don't want to use a more current controller? Better availability, cheaper, ...

Answer (score 1):

In the the part [datasheet](http://www.aplusinc.com.tw/data/apr9301v2-v2.3.pdf), it appears the playback trigger pin is a digital input pin with an integrated pull-up resistor.  In that case, you should be able to connect a digital output pin of the 8051 directly to the playback trigger pin.  You could use an open-drain output, since the device has an integrated pull-up, but a standard DIO pin should do fine as well.  You will need to drive the pin low to trigger the playback.  you may drive high or leave the pin tri-stated when inactive.

Comment: A relay would work. If they have the same ground connection then you can drive directly from the 8051.